# Image is rendering multiple times in the webpage

Tags: reactjs, json, rendering

I am creating a shopping cart with json as a database. When I try to map my images and try to render images on webpage, the pictures are rendered 25 times which is equal to my actual number of data in json file.
Kindly help to get rid of this error. My image set is rendered 25 times.

```
import React from 'react';
import products from '../productData.json';
import './style.css';


const SingleProduct = () => {
  return (
    <div >
       {
          products.map((prod)=>
            <div  className="image">
              <img  src={prod.image} style={{width:"20%"}}  alt="logo" />
            </div>
          )
       }
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleProduct
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { CartState } from '../context/Context';
import './style.css';
import SingleProduct from './SingleProduct';
import Filters from './Filters';

const Home = () => {

  const { state:{products} } = CartState();
  

  return (
    <div className='home'>
      <Filters />
      <div className="productContainer"> 
      {
            products.map((prod)=>{
          return <SingleProduct prod={prod} key={prod.id} />
        })
      }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

These are images getting repeated for 25 times same as my json has 25 data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the full `products` data is shown in component `SingleProduct` although the name suggest that it might be for just one data.

Perhaps try remove the `map()` in `SingleProduct` and just render the `prod` data from props:

```
import React from "react";
import products from "../productData.json";
import "./style.css";

const SingleProduct = ({ prod }) => {
  return (
    <div className="image">
      <img src={prod.image} style={{ width: "20%" }} alt="logo" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleProduct;
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks @John Li for the help. You are awesome!.

Comment: @Siva.subramanaian Thanks for the reply,  and if it works, I think perhaps the `import` of `products` data from json could also be omitted in `SingleProduct` as it might not be used in here anyways, just to make it cleaner.